# Detect Scroll once + in Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I am slightly new to javascript, how do I make it so when the user scrolls once, it fires a function once.
Also, how do you detect the scroll in fancybox?  I tried multiple things like .fancybox-inner but I couldn't grab it.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/bft7fb6t/3/

```js
$('.section1').click(function(){
  $.fancybox({
    type: 'inline',
    href: '#fancy-about',
    helpers : {
      overlay : {
        css : {
          'background' : 'blue'
        }
      }
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').scroll(function(){
  alert('hey');
});
});
```

```css
.parallax-window {
    min-height: 400px;  background: transparent;

}
body{
  height:2000px;
}
.section1{
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  background:black;
}

#fancy-about{
  display:none;
  color:white;
  width:500px;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax.js/1.4.2/parallax.js"></script>
<div class="section1"></div>

<div id="fancy-about">
<p>Hey, this is meLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum efficitur sed enim in mollis. Proin molestie libero id congue hendrerit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean augue libero, scelerisque id sagittis et, tristique nec ipsum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam congue maximus efficitur. Fusce malesuada, magna eu porttitor fermentum, lorem arcu fermentum mi, porta faucibus lorem mauris sed felis. Curabitur dignissim risus quam, rutrum congue tellus aliquet sit amet. Cras luctus ac lectus non sollicitudin. Sed dolor metus, tempor eleifend orci et, laoreet vulputate orci.

Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque vitae malesuada massa. Proin facilisis ligula sed turpis scelerisque, ut pellentesque felis pharetra. Praesent metus elit, semper non vehicula non, pharetra quis nunc. Phasellus purus tortor, commodo non eleifend ut, blandit in leo. Aliquam sollicitudin gravida tristique. Nulla convallis nibh id massa eleifend ullamcorper. Morbi ut eleifend nisl, nec tincidunt nunc. Donec facilisis nibh tellus, non scelerisque augue varius elementum. Cras cursus mollis lectus ac malesuada. Nulla bibendum ex malesuada, dignissim neque a, scelerisque ipsum. Etiam pretium gravida odio, ac pulvinar nulla vehicula vel. Vestibulum pellentesque neque purus, eu bibendum ligula euismod id. Cras eu tristique massa. Nunc blandit vulputate mi non maximus.</p>
<div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/0/0d/025Pikachu.png/250px-025Pikachu.png"></div><p>Hey, this is meLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum efficitur sed enim in mollis. Proin molestie libero id congue hendrerit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean augue libero, scelerisque id sagittis et, tristique nec ipsum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam congue maximus efficitur. Fusce malesuada, magna eu porttitor fermentum, lorem arcu fermentum mi, porta faucibus lorem mauris sed felis. Curabitur dignissim risus quam, rutrum congue tellus aliquet sit amet. Cras luctus ac lectus non sollicitudin. Sed dolor metus, tempor eleifend orci et, laoreet vulputate orci.

Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque vitae malesuada massa. Proin facilisis ligula sed turpis scelerisque, ut pellentesque felis pharetra. Praesent metus elit, semper non vehicula non, pharetra quis nunc. Phasellus purus tortor, commodo non eleifend ut, blandit in leo. Aliquam sollicitudin gravida tristique. Nulla convallis nibh id massa eleifend ullamcorper. Morbi ut eleifend nisl, nec tincidunt nunc. Donec facilisis nibh tellus, non scelerisque augue varius elementum. Cras cursus mollis lectus ac malesuada. Nulla bibendum ex malesuada, dignissim neque a, scelerisque ipsum. Etiam pretium gravida odio, ac pulvinar nulla vehicula vel. Vestibulum pellentesque neque purus, eu bibendum ligula euismod id. Cras eu tristique massa. Nunc blandit vulputate mi non maximus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You could set a variable like hasScrolled=true then just check for that before calling the function

Answer (score 0):

Scroll is not work than try to use alternative this mouse wheel event it is work

```js
$('.section1').click(function(){
  $.fancybox({
    type: 'inline',
    href: '#fancy-about',
    helpers : {
      overlay : {
        css : {
          'background' : 'blue'
        }
      }
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').scroll(function(){
    alert('hey');
  });
});
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){
   alert('hey');
});
```

```css
.parallax-window {
    min-height: 400px;  background: transparent;

}
body{
  height:2000px;
}
.section1{
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  background:black;
}

#fancy-about{
  display:none;
  color:white;
  width:500px;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax.js/1.4.2/parallax.js"></script>
<div class="section1"></div>

<div id="fancy-about">
<p>Hey, this is meLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum efficitur sed enim in mollis. Proin molestie libero id congue hendrerit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean augue libero, scelerisque id sagittis et, tristique nec ipsum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam congue maximus efficitur. Fusce malesuada, magna eu porttitor fermentum, lorem arcu fermentum mi, porta faucibus lorem mauris sed felis. Curabitur dignissim risus quam, rutrum congue tellus aliquet sit amet. Cras luctus ac lectus non sollicitudin. Sed dolor metus, tempor eleifend orci et, laoreet vulputate orci.

Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque vitae malesuada massa. Proin facilisis ligula sed turpis scelerisque, ut pellentesque felis pharetra. Praesent metus elit, semper non vehicula non, pharetra quis nunc. Phasellus purus tortor, commodo non eleifend ut, blandit in leo. Aliquam sollicitudin gravida tristique. Nulla convallis nibh id massa eleifend ullamcorper. Morbi ut eleifend nisl, nec tincidunt nunc. Donec facilisis nibh tellus, non scelerisque augue varius elementum. Cras cursus mollis lectus ac malesuada. Nulla bibendum ex malesuada, dignissim neque a, scelerisque ipsum. Etiam pretium gravida odio, ac pulvinar nulla vehicula vel. Vestibulum pellentesque neque purus, eu bibendum ligula euismod id. Cras eu tristique massa. Nunc blandit vulputate mi non maximus.</p>
<div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/0/0d/025Pikachu.png/250px-025Pikachu.png"></div><p>Hey, this is meLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum efficitur sed enim in mollis. Proin molestie libero id congue hendrerit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean augue libero, scelerisque id sagittis et, tristique nec ipsum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam congue maximus efficitur. Fusce malesuada, magna eu porttitor fermentum, lorem arcu fermentum mi, porta faucibus lorem mauris sed felis. Curabitur dignissim risus quam, rutrum congue tellus aliquet sit amet. Cras luctus ac lectus non sollicitudin. Sed dolor metus, tempor eleifend orci et, laoreet vulputate orci.

Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque vitae malesuada massa. Proin facilisis ligula sed turpis scelerisque, ut pellentesque felis pharetra. Praesent metus elit, semper non vehicula non, pharetra quis nunc. Phasellus purus tortor, commodo non eleifend ut, blandit in leo. Aliquam sollicitudin gravida tristique. Nulla convallis nibh id massa eleifend ullamcorper. Morbi ut eleifend nisl, nec tincidunt nunc. Donec facilisis nibh tellus, non scelerisque augue varius elementum. Cras cursus mollis lectus ac malesuada. Nulla bibendum ex malesuada, dignissim neque a, scelerisque ipsum. Etiam pretium gravida odio, ac pulvinar nulla vehicula vel. Vestibulum pellentesque neque purus, eu bibendum ligula euismod id. Cras eu tristique massa. Nunc blandit vulputate mi non maximus.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your code work, you have to move the scroll function into the click function:

```
$('.section1').click(function(){
 $.fancybox({
  type: 'inline',
  href: '#fancy-about',
  helpers : {
   overlay : {
    css : {
      'background' : 'blue'
    }
  }
}
});
  $('.fancybox-inner').bind('scroll',function() {
   alert("ciao");
  }); 

});
```

[your fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/bft7fb6t/5/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to call scroll function on fancybox aftershow for the work fine.

```
$('.section1').click(function(){
  $.fancybox({
    type: 'inline',
    href: '#fancy-about',
    helpers : {
      overlay : {
        css : {
          'background' : 'blue'
        }
      }
    },
    afterShow: function() {
        $( '.fancybox-inner' ).scroll(function(){
                     alert('hey');
        });
    }
  });
});
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bft7fb6t/7/)